# What is the first episode of Stargate that Teal'c says "Indeed"

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

So, I'm recently re-watching Stargate SG-1, and I noticed something odd. Teal'c doesn't say Indeed... It got me wondering, when is the first time that Teal'c says Indeed in the series?

Specifically, I'm looking for Indeed as a single word, not as a part of a sentence.

Comment: [Indeed.](http://youtu.be/XtPgr94VYA4)

Comment: Indeed. I kept waiting... Wow, near the end of season 2!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [The Indeed Project](http://www.skulldude.com/sg1/indeed/season02.html):

- The first time Teal'c says it in a sentence is in 2x11, The Tok'Ra Part 1
- The first time he says it stand-alone is in 2x19, One False Step

Comment: Wow, the Indeed Project...

Comment: Holy Geocities Batman!  That is an *ugly* site.

Comment: Geocities is the first thought I had too. Nothing beats a star background and a red/green blink tag. And Marquee can't forget Marquee.... And frames. Oh and that horrid counter.

Answer (score 2):

He says it in ["Holiday" (217)](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s2/217.shtml) while he's stuck in O'Neil's body.
However, he's not the first one to say it, I'm pretty sure I heard a keeper said it first (probably in the first season).